# Produce unique ids for a list of lists with words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of lists with pairs of words and want to depict words on ids. Ids should be from 0 till the len(set(words)). The list now looks like that:

```
[['pluripotent', 'Scharte'],
 ['Halswirbel', 'präventiv'],
 ['Kleiber', 'Blauspecht'],
 ['Kleiber', 'Scheidung'],
 ['Nillenlutscher', 'Salzstangenlecker']]
```

The result should have the same formats, but with ids instead. So for example:

```
[[0, 1],
 [2, 3],
 [4, 5],
 [4, 6],
 [7, 8]]
```

I have till now this, but it doesn't give me the right output:

```
def words_to_ids(labels):
  vocabulary = []
  word_to_id = {}
  ids = []
  for word1,word2 in labels:
      vocabulary.append(word1)
      vocabulary.append(word2)

  for i, word in enumerate(vocabulary):
      word_to_id [word] = i
  for word1,word2 in labels:
      ids.append([word_to_id [word1], word_to_id [word1]])
  print(ids)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0], [2, 2], [6, 6], [6, 6], [8, 8]]
```

It is repeating ids where there are unique words.

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to start at 0, given your attempted output. Feel free to correct these assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors. First, you have a simple typo, here:

```
for word1,word2 in labels:
    ids.append([word_to_id [word1], word_to_id [word1]])
```

You are adding the id for `word1` **twice**, there. Correct the second `word1` to look up `word2` instead.

Next, you are not testing if you have seen a word before, so for `'Kleiber'` you first give it the id `4`, then overwrite that entry with `6` the next iteration. You need to give *unique* words numbers, not all words:

```
counter = 0
for word in vocabulary:
    if word not in word_to_id:
        word_to_id[word] = counter
        counter += 1
```

or you could simply not add a word to `vocabulary` if you already have that word listed. You don't really need a separate `vocabulary` list here, by the way. A separate loop doesn't buy you anything, so the following works too:

```
word_to_id = {}
counter = 0
for words in labels:
    for word in words:
        word_to_id [word] = counter
        counter += 1
```

You can simplify your code quite a bit by using a [`defaultdict` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to supply default values:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

def words_to_ids(labels):
    word_ids = defaultdict(count().__next__)
    return [[word_ids[w1], word_ids[w2]] for w1, w2 in labels]
```

The `count()` object gives you the next integer value in a series each time `__next__` is called, and `defaultdict()` will call that each time you try to access a key that doesn't yet exist in the dictionary. Together, they ensure a unique ID for each unique word.

Comment: oh, thanx. the only thing is, now i get [[0, 1], [2, 3], [6, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]] So I ask me, what happens with number 4

Comment: @NastjaKr: you gave `Kleiber` a number *twice*. I'll update.

Comment: yes, some word appear in the list several time, but the id of it should be the same everywhere

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. You made a typo by repeating a lookup of `word1` in `word_to_id`.
2. When constructing your `word_to_id` dictionary you need to consider unique values only.

For example, in Python 3.7+ you can take advantage of insertion-ordered dictionaries:

```
for i, word in enumerate(dict.fromkeys(vocabulary)):
    word_to_id[word] = i

for word1, word2 in labels:
    ids.append([word_to_id[word1], word_to_id[word2]])
```

An alternative for versions pre-3.7 is to use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) or the [`itertools` `unique_everseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

If there is no ordering requirement, you can just use `set(vocabulary)`.

Comment: There is no requirement for the numbers to be ordered matching the input order, so `set()` *would* have sufficed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Fair enough, `set` is fine then!